# Using Mesos instead of Sharding Database

Tags: mongodb, mesos, database

Is it possible to run a database like Mongodb on Mesosphere and when its time to scale up, add more nodes to the Mesos cluster without sharding, rather than adding more Mongodb instances and sharding.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo specifically? probably not, no. 
Currently there's no support for persistent storage and Mongo isn't really dynamic
enough to run well in that sort of environment.

You could try Cassandra or Elasticsearch to get an idea of the concepts - a Google
should show tutorials for both.